# multer file upload: the file is showing undefined in the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload, multer

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div className='file-form pt-16 flex flex-col px-14 gap-7  sm:px-[140px] md:px-[170px] lg:px-[230px] xl:px-[300px]'>
    <form className='bg-[#02203c] flex flex-col' onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType='multipart/formdata' >
      <div className=" flex flex-col gap-2 ">
        <label className='text-white font-thin text-lg'>Attach your cv/resume</label>

        <input className="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400"
          aria-describedby="file_input_help" name='' id="file_input" type="file" required
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleFile(e)
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='pt-4 flex justify-center'>
        <button type='submit'
          name="image" // Add the name attribute to match the backend expectations
          required className={'justify-self-end bg-blue-400 text-center px-4 py-1 rounded-md text-white hover:bg-blue-500 duration-300'} >Upload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Here is the function that is called in the HTML:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState('');

  const handleFile = (e) => {
    console.log(file);
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);

    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
      const response = await fileUpload(formData, token);
      // console.log(response.data); // Handle the response from the server

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Here is the function that is called for the end point for posting the image:

```
export const fileUpload = async (file, token) => {
   const config = {
      headers: {
         'Authorization': token
      }
   };

   return axios.post('/user/file-upload', file, config);
}
```

Here is the server side code of the endpoint:

```
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

const router = express.Router();

 const userfileUpload = async (req,res) =>{
    console.log(req.file,req.body);
}
router.post('/user/register', upload.single('image'), userRegister);
```

The output when logging is `undefined {}`.

Comment: Can you confirm from the network that the request header content type is multipart/form-data ? Also please ensure that you are using app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) in backend.